# How can observe my fast source on thread-pool queue

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

Need help making an observable start on the main thread, and then move on to a pool of threads allowing the source to continue emitting new items (regardless if they are still being processed in the pool of threads).

This is my example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(1,10);

    source.map(i -> sleep(i, 10))
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Emitting " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map(i -> sleep(i * 10, 300))
            .subscribe( i -> System.out.println("Received " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

    sleep(-1, 30000);
}

private static int sleep(int i, int time) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(time);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return i;
}
```

which always prints:

```
Emitting 1 on thread main
Emitting 2 on thread main
Emitting 3 on thread main
Received 10 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Emitting 4 on thread main
Emitting 5 on thread main
Emitting 6 on thread main
Received 20 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Emitting 7 on thread main
Emitting 8 on thread main
Emitting 9 on thread main
Received 30 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Emitting 10 on thread main
Received 40 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Received 50 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Received 60 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Received 70 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Received 80 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Received 90 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
Received 100 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
```

Although items are emitted on the main thread as supposed, I want them to move on to the computation/IO thread-pool **afterwards**.

Should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think everything is happening so quickly in this example, it is appearing to block before the `observeOn()` even though it is not. Let me see if I can exaggerate sleeping time in a way where it proves it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you were slowing down the source emissions enough, and they were emitting so quickly that all items were emitted before the `observeOn()` had a chance to schedule them.

Try sleeping to 500ms instead of 10ms. You will then see interleaving like you would expect.

```
public class JavaLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(1,10);

        source.map(i -> sleep(i, 500))
                .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Emitting " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map(i -> sleep(i * 10, 250))
                .subscribe( i -> System.out.println("Received " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

        sleep(-1, 30000);
    }

    private static int sleep(int i, int time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Emitting 1 on thread main
Emitting 2 on thread main
Emitting 3 on thread main
Received 10 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Emitting 4 on thread main
Received 20 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Emitting 5 on thread main
Emitting 6 on thread main
Received 30 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Emitting 7 on thread main
Emitting 8 on thread main
Received 40 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Emitting 9 on thread main
Emitting 10 on thread main
Received 50 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Received 60 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Received 70 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Received 80 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Received 90 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Received 100 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
```

**UPDATE - Parallelized Version**

```
public class JavaLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(1,10);

        source.map(i -> sleep(i, 250))
                .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Emitting " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
                .flatMap(i -> 
                    Observable.just(i)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .map(i2 -> sleep(i2 * 10, 500))
                )
                .subscribe( i -> System.out.println("Received " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

        sleep(-1, 30000);
    }

    private static int sleep(int i, int time) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Emitting 1 on thread main
Emitting 2 on thread main
Emitting 3 on thread main
Received 10 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Emitting 4 on thread main
Received 20 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-4
Received 30 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
Emitting 5 on thread main
Received 40 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-2
Emitting 6 on thread main
Received 50 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Emitting 7 on thread main
Received 60 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-4
Emitting 8 on thread main
Received 70 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
Emitting 9 on thread main
Received 80 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-2
Emitting 10 on thread main
Received 90 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-3
Received 100 on thread RxComputationThreadPool-4
```

Comment: Keep in mind also, the `observeOn()` is not processing items on "a pool of threads". It's just one thread from that pool. If you want to utilize all threads in the pool you need to [utilize some parallelization patterns](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html)

Comment: In the ouput you show its still always using 1 thread out of the pool. But like you mention in your comment, you were expecting that, but I wasn't.

Comment: Yes, `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` only redirect emissions to another *single* thread. If you want to truly parallelize and use all threads available in a Scheduler, you need to do some FlatMap kung-fu. I put a parallelized version of the code here. https://gist.github.com/thomasnield/81b783303564376b904d789480405e50

Comment: I would also read the article on parallelization closely, because a lot of people assume and get confused on how to do it correctly. http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html

Comment: I was afraid of that solution. By creating a new sequence (Observable) you get to send it to a new thread but that way I'm not sure how the backpressure operator will work (source might be a lot faster at times).

Comment: Could you perhaps change your answer so it reflects on true parallelization and not so much about the timing? Guess it could help others understand better this. Thanks for your help Thomas!

Comment: Done. I wouldn't worry terribly much about the backpressure unless you are doing something extreme. `flatMap()` should handle that for you. I'm not an expert at all in backpressure so I'll have to defer to @akarnokd or @dave-moten if your concerns are warranted.

Comment: @ThomasN. would you mind taking a look at a similar question about your article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914509/rxjava-only-one-emission-is-allowed-to-travel-up-the-observable-chain-at-a-ti/44914641#44914641